# Error: control Reaches end of non void function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return, numerical-methods

I am learning *C++* and I copied this code from a textbook, while compiling the code, an error appears at the end. The error says:

> Control Reaches end of non-void function

and its located at the end of the code:

```
#include "ComplexNumber.hpp"
#include <cmath>

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{
mRealPart = 0.0;
mImaginaryPart = 0.0;
}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double x, double y)
{
mRealPart = x;
mImaginaryPart = y;
}

double ComplexNumber::CalculateModulus() const
{
return sqrt(mRealPart*mRealPart+
            mImaginaryPart*mImaginaryPart);
}
double ComplexNumber::CalculateArgument() const
{
return atan2(mImaginaryPart, mRealPart);
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::CalculatePower(double n) const
{
double modulus = CalculateModulus();
double argument = CalculateArgument();
double mod_of_result = pow(modulus, n);
double arg_of_result = argument*n;
double real_part = mod_of_result*cos(arg_of_result);
double imag_part = mod_of_result*sin(arg_of_result);
ComplexNumber z(real_part, imag_part);
return z;
}

ComplexNumber& ComplexNumber::operator=(const ComplexNumber& z)
{
mRealPart = z.mRealPart;
mImaginaryPart = z.mImaginaryPart;
return *this;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator-() const
{
ComplexNumber w;
w.mRealPart = -mRealPart;
w.mImaginaryPart = -mImaginaryPart;
return w;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(const ComplexNumber& z) const
{
ComplexNumber w;
w.mRealPart = mRealPart + z.mRealPart;
w.mImaginaryPart = mImaginaryPart + z.mImaginaryPart;
return w;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output,
                     const ComplexNumber& z)
{
output << "(" << z.mRealPart << " ";
if (z.mImaginaryPart >= 0.0)
{
    output << " + " << z.mImaginaryPart << "i)";
}
else
{
    output << "- " << -z.mImaginaryPart << "i)";
}
} //-------->>>>**"Control Reaches end of non-void function"**
```

Comment: Whatever textbook this is from, I don't imagine it's all that good.

Comment: The book is by Joe Pitt-Francis and Jonathan Whiteley. "Guide to Scientific Computing in C++". I am reading it, because I am supposed to do some numerical calculations using object oriented approach and is the only one I could find, If you have any suggestion, i will be glad to hear them.

Comment: To be quite honest, scientists and *good* programming don't go together very well. You'll end up getting a lot more out of those books that aren't designed for teaching the language if you know it well enough to not pick up bad habits. For the language, we have a nice list of [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks Chris!, I am a scientist and I am more used to work with Java and Fortran, now I have to work in a project where we are using C++. And you are right. Even without understanding C++ I can spot many bad programing habits. I will check the list of books suggested. And try to improve the image you have of scientist in the programming world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `operator<<` is defined to return `std::ostream&`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const ComplexNumber& z)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but you have no return statements, this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and means you can not rely on the behavior of the program, the results are unpredictable. It looks like you should have:

```
return output ;
```

at the end of the function. We can see this is undefined behavior from the draft C++ standard section `6.6.3` The return statement paragraph 2 which says:

> [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function. [...]

Answer (score 1):

The function claims to return something:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const ComplexNumber& z)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but there is no `return` statement at the end. You should add one:

```
return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output,
                     const ComplexNumber& z)
{
output << "(" << z.mRealPart << " ";
if (z.mImaginaryPart >= 0.0)
{
    output << " + " << z.mImaginaryPart << "i)";
}
else
{
    output << "- " << -z.mImaginaryPart << "i)";
}
}
```

has return type `std::ostream &` However it returns nothing. I think there is a typo There should be

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output,
                     const ComplexNumber& z)
{
output << "(" << z.mRealPart << " ";
if (z.mImaginaryPart >= 0.0)
{
    output << " + " << z.mImaginaryPart << "i)";
}
else
{
    output << "- " << -z.mImaginaryPart << "i)";
}

return output;
}
```